# What context do quantifiers make valid expressions?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, propositions

Say I have a formal language such that x is an individual constant and symbolically has a particular value (say 2) a proposition such as x+1=3 already has the value of true, and I cannot define a binding operation such as a quantifier on to x like ∀xP(x) as this is a badly formed sentence and has no truth value.

Say I have a free variable x in my formal language, I can in the context where x can change to values in the domain of reals define ∀xP(x) as either being true or false.

If I were to have x as a varying value and wanted to look at (substitute) x=2 for example would it still be wrong for a quantified expression to have a truth value when x=2? Would it still be wrongly formed sentence (in the case of trying to quantify over a constant)? as x is still free to vary from values other than 2 more generally so could it have a truth value when x is two but still able to vary, or does it act as if x is a constant and I can only talk about quantification in the more free case where x has no particular value of interest e.g., when I haven't defined 'when x=....'.

Comment: Not very clear... In formula **x+1=3** you can "instantiate" free variable **x** with value **2** and the result is a true arithmetical sentence. In formula **∀x(x+1=3)** there is no free variable: the expression is a sentence that has a definite truth value in a suitable interpretation: for example, in the domain of *natural* numbers it is false.

Comment: Having said that, what do you mean with "valid expressions"? A syntactically correct expression? This must be specified by the [syntax of the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax).

Comment: Can you continue the example? What would you write down when you "want to look at x=2"?

Comment: For more on this topic, you can see textbooks: [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), [Simpson](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m571-08/simpson.pdf), [Chiswell & Hodges](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~belardinelli/Documents/Logique/Mathematical-Logic-ChiswellHodges.pdf).

Comment: There is language made of *symbols* and there is a world made of *objects*: words and sentences (expressions=strings of symbols that are syntactically correct=well-formed) speaks of objects and facts of the world. The same for a formal language:  **2+1=3** is a sentence of the formal language of arithmetic that expresses a true fact about the "world of number" while **∀x(x+1=3)** is a false sentence (about the same arithmetical world. We cannot substitute variable **x** into **∀x(x+1=3)** with the constant **2** (the name for the number *two*) because **x** is not free in the formula.

Comment: While the substitution operation **(x+1=3)[2 → x]** produces the sentence **(2+1=3)** the substitution **∀x(x+1=3)[2 → x]**, that is formally correct, produces **∀x(x+1=3)**.

Comment: @DavidGudeman for example we may have substitute 2 for x as we often do in standard mathematics and define therefore x=2 and p(x) is true, can we have the quantified expression also be true when x=2 or as x is bound by the quantifier does it make no sense?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was told given a constant in a logical language, to try to quantify over it is not a valid or properly formed expression, so if we have a 'varying' term such as x and we are looking in the substitution case for 2 is the quantified expression meaningful for x=2?

Comment: Correct, we quantify variables not constants.

Comment: We do not subst quantified vars, see comment above.

Comment: I'll definitely read more into it, I think it's more about my concept of substitution and context being a bit incorrect.

Comment: I think what is going on is that you are confusing various things: meaning of a name, substitution of a name, and programming-language variables. In mathematics, when you say "x=2", then x means 2 everywhere it occurs in that formula or chain of formulas. If you want to explore an expression with x=2, then you substitute 2 for x in the formula.

Comment: yes, I think he idea of a 'general variable' x and then saying 'if x=2' is somewhat confusing because yes, we replace x everywhere in the formula but the idea of 'change' is so vague, does it change simply because we're interested in different values? How the structure changes for different numbers? Perhaps a different replacement notation is better, trying to differ from how something works in the 'constant' case and the 'at a particular value' case comes from this as well.

Comment: I assume my mistake is that given a formula P(x) we can use a quantified formula to bind it and talk about the values 'if' we substituted into it, but to actually substitute into it and try to use the quantifier makes no sense, as if x=2 the bound expression would still have the variable x but with a different meaning as we cannot substitute 2 into x and it becomes a little bit meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I have a formal language such that x is an individual constant and symbolically has a particular value (say 2) a proposition such as x+1=3 already has the value of true, and I cannot define a binding operation such as a quantifier on to x like ∀xP(x) as this is a badly formed sentence and has no truth value.

Then the symbols "x" and "2" are synonymous. "x" is just another way of writing "2", and the statement "x = 2" is a tautology (like "2 = 2" or "x = x"). This is not the usual convention in mathematics, but if you want to define your syntax in that way, you can do so.

> Say I have a free variable x in my formal language, I can in the context where x can change to values in the domain of reals define ∀xP(x) as either being true or false.

Earlier, you told us that "x" means "2" at the level of *syntax*. Now you are telling us that "x" is a variable. This means that "x" has two different meanings, and the sentence "x + 1 = 3" is syntactically ambiguous - you could mean "x, the variable, plus one is three" or you could mean "two, the number, plus one is three". Normally, we try to avoid this in formal languages, because the whole point of using formal languages is to eliminate syntactic ambiguity. As a result, it is going to be very difficult to engage in formal reasoning with such an ambiguous language.

This is entirely different from the *semantic* notion of writing something like "let x = 2." In that context, "x" is still syntactically a variable, but we are describing the [interpretation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/) of the sentence in which the variable *x* takes on the value two. The variable *x* is a different object from the symbol "x," because the former is a semantic object, and the latter a syntactic object. This distinction between syntax and semantics is, I believe, the point of confusion in your question. Substitution is a syntactic transformation which converts a semantic interpretation back into "pure" syntax. Importantly, substitution preserves the semantic meaning of a sentence, under a given interpretation, but does not preserve its syntax, nor its semantic meaning under other interpretations.

Similarly, we must distinguish between the "∀" symbol (a syntactic object) and the universal quantifier (a semantic object). The quantifier symbol "∀" binds to a variable symbol such as "x," and the (semantic) universal quantifier binds to a (semantic) variable such as *x*. Although the "∀" symbol can be described in purely syntactic terms (by appealing to substitution), at a semantic level, it must be understood in terms of semantic interpretations. Specifically, it states that the formula evaluates to true under every interpretation of *x* (possibly subject to other requirements, such as the axioms of the surrounding theory).

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, If I am doing normal Mathematics, and I have what would be a constant 'a' in the context of my problem and have it with a value of '2', would that be similar to having x be another name for two as in a formal language?

Comment: I guess my issue, is differing from the 'variable at a value in our model' vs a 'constant'.

Comment: @user1007028: Mathematicians do that sort of thing from time to time, when they introduce symbols like π or e, and physicists when they introduce symbols like c. Ultimately, it's not really that significant whether you think of it as a syntactic constant or a semantic constant, but you do need to be consistent about this. If it's a syntactic constant, then it can't appear bound to a quantifier, because it's just another way of writing a number. If it's a semantic constant, then quantifying over it is not ungrammatical, but it might not make logical sense.

Comment: What would be an example of a syntactic constant and semantic constant? For example the speed of light in a vacuum (c) or perhaps I have a function f(x)=ax and I have decided a=2 from now on, implying ax=2x? Obviously as Mathematicians we will use a symbol 'a' that has no fixed value and call it a 'constant' I would understand that this usage of the word is not correct in Logic?